# the_post_thumbnail returns outside the the hyperlink

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

when I use `get_the_post_thumbnail` it returns the featured image default size inside `<a></a>` but when I use it without get to insert the predefined size name in function file it returns the desired size but outside the hyperlink.

```
<?php
$args = array('showposts' => 25);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if( $the_query->have_posts() ): 
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();     
        echo '<span><li><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">' .the_post_thumbnail('shapely-grid').' '.get_the_title().'</a> <p>' .get_the_excerpt($limit).'</p></li></span>';
    endwhile; 
    echo '</ul>';
endif; 
wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/ you'll see that the function does an immediate 'echo' as do most wp functions that start with 'the_'.     so either use https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/ or change code to something like:

```
echo '<span><li><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">' ;
the_post_thumbnail('shapely-grid');
echo ' '.get_the_title().'</a> <p>' .get_the_excerpt($limit).'</p></li></span>';
```